# WCF Multiple Clients

Tags: c#, wcf, server, client

I am currently working on an instant messenger application. Once a client connects to the server and sends a msg it works just fine. A second client connects, both clients chatting and everything is working perfectly. The problem comes when the 2 clients send a msg simultaneously. Then both clients freeze (in debug I get a timeout) but the msg is shown fine to the other clients in the chat.

This is the server's behavior:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

app.config behavior:

```
<behavior name="Behave">
            <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100"
 maxConcurrentSessions="100"
 maxConcurrentInstances="100" />
          </behavior>
```

I am a newbie when it comes to WCF and I am not sure I understand it completely. I have tried changing stuff around but nothing seems to be helping. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.
If further code is needed I will provide it upon requests.

Comment: did u try to change InstanceContextMode  = InstanceContextMode.PerCall ??

Comment: @NadeemKhoury I have tried it already but I need to use singleton. If I use PerCall, or PerSession, depending on which of the two, then my application gets messed up. What happens is, the 2 clients (or any other clients) will NOT be able to chat because a new object is created for each of them. They are able to send messages, even though neither of them will be visible to the other one. I am not sure if my explanation is good enough for you to understand the behaviour of the application so please let me know if it is not.

Comment: Going over everything. It's just the UI of the 2 clients freezing. And that's about it. I think the problem lies in synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make the call to background Thread, not same thread. 
and here is the deal:

1. you should define `private SynchronizationContext _SyncContext;`

2.and in Constructor:

```
_SyncContext = SynchronizationContext .Current;
```

3. and in your client side add this code inside the method event handler.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(()=>
{

    SendOrPostCallBack callback = new SendOrPostCallback(arg=>
    {


    ** your logic here need to be marshalled**
    }

    _SyncContext.Send(callback, null); 
}
```

tell me if it worked with you bro. Happy Coding.

Comment: That was close enough to give me a basic idea of what was wrong. Inside my client, I ran an asynchronous operation using Task when sending a request to the server and it fixed my problem. I didn't need to implement SynchronizationContext at all. Thank you!